# Flexible search or sql query using three tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sap-commerce-cloud

I have three tables Order,Customer,Address.

Can i know how to join three tables in flexible search to find out to which address(primary/default address or secondary address) the order of the customer is delivered ?

Note : primary address is the address created during customer registration.

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output to the question

Comment: You're not supposed to use directly sql queries, always use FlexibleSearch in hybris!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this you want  ?

```
select {order.deliveryAddress} from {Order as order},{Customer as customer} where {order.user}={customer.pk} and {customer.uid} = ?customerID
```

OR

```
select {address.pk} from {Order as order},{Customer as customer},{Address as address} where {order.deliveryAddress}={address.pk} and {order.user}={customer.pk} and {customer.uid} = ?customerID
```

OR

```
select {order:deliveryAddress} from {Order as order JOIN Customer as customer ON {order:user}={customer:pk}} where {customer:uid} = ?customerID
```